DPI mismatch between the preview and actual layout in emulator
using a custom emulator with 1080x2400 px resolution and i have also set its DPI to 400 because the phone i have is 395ppi/dpi and 400 is the closest possible dpi setting for the emulator but it's not constraints that I'm talking about, i use a constraint layout to hold them in place properly, it's like they don't move but there's a DPI mismatch between the Emulator and whatever DPI the layout preview is, do i need to set every view's DPI individually to fit properly in a 1080x2400 400dpi screen or there's some sort of setting for the layout preview to accurately mimic a 400dpi screen?
Constrainted them properly thinking it would do the job but constraints just hold them in place, and they are in place like they're supposed to rather being enlarged as if there's a DPI mismatch.
